# Trouble with Laravel Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-6

I am currently working on a Laravel project and encountering an issue with Eloquent relationships. I have two models, **User** and **Post**, and I'm trying to establish a one-to-many relationship between them. However, I'm facing issues when trying to retrieve the related posts for a user

**User Model**

```
class Post extends Model {
    // ...
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post extends Model {
    // ...
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to retrieve the posts for a user using the following below code

```
$user = User::find(1);
$posts = $user->posts;
```

I'm not getting the expected results and $posts is empty I have ensured that there are posts with the user in the database

Comment: You posted the same model twice. Also, there is an example in docs that answers this. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse Posts belong to Users. Users have many posts

Comment: Please post your User model as well and columns from both the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing you need to do is create a hasMany relationship in the **User** model,
then create a belongsTo relationship in the **Post** model.

**User Model**

```
class User extends Model{
    // ...
    public function post(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
    }
}
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post extends Model{
    // ...
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'foreign_key', 'owner_key');
    }
}
```

For more details, you can see it in the Laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you User model with this

```
class User extends Model{
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```